# Passing Parameters to a score_func in scikit during cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to compute the micro average precision in scikit during cross validation.

The docs here:

http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/modules/cross_validation.html

Say you can pass in a custom scoring function from the metrics module such as metrics.precision_score:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score

But by default it computes the scores for each class. If I try and pass in `average="micro"` like so:

```
cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, x, label, cv=5,
score_func=metrics.precision_score(average="micro"))
```

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: precision_score() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I can't pass in all of the other arguments it wants (`y_true`, `y_pred`) as I don't know what `y_pred` is.

Is there a way to get the micro average precision from cross validation in scikit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are *calling* (with argument `average`) `metrics.precision_score` instead of passing the function itself. An **ad hoc** method to remedy this is to create a function

```
def micro_average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred):
    metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average="micro")
```

and then use it as your `score_func`, ie `score_func=micro_average_precision_score`.

On an **important side note**: `score_func` is deprecated (since `0.13` if I am not mistaken). You are referring to scikit learn docs of version 0.10. Is that the version you use?

The new way of passing scorers is by using *scorer objects*. The associated keyword is `scoring=` and not `score_func=`. You can make a scorer object out of any scoring function, for example the one defined above, by using `make_scorer`

```
from sklearn.metrics.score import make_scorer
scorer = make_scorer(micro_average_precision_score, greater_is_better=True)
```

or, equivalently:

```
scorer = make_scorer(metrics.precision_score, 
                     greater_is_better=True, average="micro")
```

Comment: For some reason when I use either of these methods i get the following error : Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'] . This error occurs when my training set is being fit to the model